# Pressing the enter key with multiple submit buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a single form with multiple submit buttons that are then handled using the $_POST information. The default behaviour when pressing enter is of course for the first button on the page to be "clicked" however I would like the button that is clicked to depend on where the user is in the form at the time they click it. A stripped back excerpt of php code is shown below. Note that I have tried using onkeydown/onkeypress/onkeyupp and using the event keycode (where it equals 13) to then document.getElementById("buttonName").click() but this doesn't seem to work- the first button on the form is still the one clicked.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // move to next page
}

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
   // add item to this page
}

$html .= '<input type="text" class="text" name="submitInfo" id="submitInfo">'; // if enter is clicked while in this textbox, the submit button should be clicked

$html .= '<input type="text" class="text" name="OptionalAddInfo" id="OptionalAddInfo">'; // if enter is clicked while in this textbox, the add button should be clicked

$html .= '<input type="submit" class="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add" onClick="return addItem();">';

$html .= '<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return submitForm();">';

echo $html;
```

Comment: Why don't you use two forms? Or regarding your attempt with using `onkeydown` to test for key 13 in the text field, did you also cancel the keydown event's default behaviour?

Comment: Please add your javascript code as well

Comment: yep, I also cancelled the default behaviour with the javascript before telling it to click the other button.

Multiple forms may end up being the option I'm forced to go with but it's not my preferred one for a few reasons. The first is that all of this information is really for the one "form", as I tried to imply there is necessary submission info, but also some optional info that could be added in (which requires some fetching based off user input). All of this is then submitted. So all of the information really belongs together. The layout also makes multiple forms non-ideal.

Comment: the javascript doesn't really do much in this case, in fact it's mostly handled through the $_POST data. The add button would check for valid inputs then query a database to return some information to add to the page (and also to be saved later). The submit button would check for valid inputs and then redirect to a new page.

Comment: for the purposes of the above, you can essentially replace return addItem(); and return submitForm(); with return true;

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery.Hotkeys To work with enter key [hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

```
 jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'return', function () {
                    $("body #submit").trigger("click");
                    return false;
                });
```